# Confused about promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I've got the following code, and I cannot understand why it doesn't do what I want. as a newbie both in JS and in jQuery, I'm confused with:

1) Even if I don't write any code inside ready() function the promises run. I mean, the promises run even if I don't call them. 
2) The intent of this code is to print 1, 2, then pause 3 seconds, print 3 and print END. Instead, it prints 1, 2, END and after three seconds, 3.

I found other examples both here and on other sites and blogs, but being a newbie in JS I haven't understood them. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $.when(f1)
    .then(f2)
    .then(f3)
    .then(final);
});

function prn(texto) {
  $('p').append(texto);
}

var f1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('1<br><br>'));
  reject('err');
});

var f2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('2<br><br>'));
  reject('err');
});

var f3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(prn('3<br><br>'));
    reject('err');
  }, 3000);
});

var final = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('END<br><br>'));
  reject('err');
});
```

Comment: You're assigning the promise to a variable, that's why it runs. What you really want to do is to create a function that returns the promise. This function is what you need to call then.

Comment: In this case, the promises are resolved and rejected immediately when defined. Note they are assigned to your variables, not generated by them. You probably mean to do `let f1 = () => new Promise...` - i.e. _return_ a Promise object instead of declaring one.

Comment: `the promises run even if I don't call them` - you have called them. You created them (`new Promise`) and you have resolved them immediately (the callback passed into `new Promise` is invoked immediately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your code,

1. You are doing both resolve and reject , either do resolve or reject. In this case reject is never called.
2. Your concern that it is being called without even having code in .ready function ---- You are directly executing the promises, like they are executing then and there itself.

```js
var f1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('1<br><br>'));
  reject('err');
});
```

This will execute immediately the moment it sees the code.

3. Promises once resolved or rejected ,their work is done. They cannot be resolved again. Since they are already resolved (the moment you defined they are resolved) and even though you call them again in load function , they are not going to resolve and the code inside of your .load is not outputting any thing.

TO avoid all , keep the promises in function and return them when function is called
I changed code to run in normal JS...

```js
var test = function (){
  Promise.resolve().then(f1)
    .then(f2)
    .then(f3)
    .then(final);
};

function prn(texto) {
 console.log(texto);
}

var f1 = function(){ return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('1<br><br>'));
})};

var f2 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('2<br><br>'));
});}

var f3 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(prn('3<br><br>'));
  }, 3000);
});}

var final = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(prn('END<br><br>'));
});}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once a Promise is defined, it might start running if possible.

The then waits if run hasn't ended yet, or returns the value of `resolve` if the function inside has concluded.

You can avoid having the promise run before it should by defining a factory function, i.e. a function that'll construct the Promise only when it's called.